# closing browser error - change behavior

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver, firewatir

I'm experiencing some strange behavior with Watir when I want to close the browser.

```
brs = Watir::Browser.new
=> #<Watir::Browser:0x1035fc1f8 url="about:blank" title="">
brs.close
=> true
brs
NoMethodError: undefined method `closed?' for nil:NilClass
```

The browser is closed properly (as expected) but after that I'm unable to operate with the class / instance.

Why is that happening?

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you want to do something after closing the browser?  Could you not achieve the same results before the browser is closed?

Comment: I want to close the browser and destroy the object, which I'm unable to do with current behavior.

Comment: you have tags for three different varieties of watir, but no require statement in your code fragment, so it is impossible to tell which one you are using, which could make a big difference..  are you using Watir, the defunct Firewatir, or Watir-Webdriver?  Also please do a `gem list` command from your command line and report the versions of anything related to watir or webdriver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not getting the error message:

```
$ irb
1.9.3-p125 :001 > require "watir-webdriver"
 => true 
1.9.3-p125 :002 > b = Watir::Browser.new
 => #<Watir::Browser:0x7e1df9f913a40838 url="about:blank" title=""> 
1.9.3-p125 :003 > b.close
 => true 
1.9.3-p125 :004 > b
 => #<Watir::Browser:0x7e1df9f913a40838 closed=true>
```

Environment:

```
- Mac OS X 10.7.3
- Firefox 12.0

$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]

$ gem -v
1.8.23

$ gem list *webdriver
...
selenium-webdriver (2.21.2)
watir-webdriver (0.5.5)
...
```

Comment: Great, I updated ruby and gems and now it seems to be okay. Is there any way to find out if browser is open or closed?

Comment: Please create a new question and let us know what are you trying to do. Why would you want to know if browser is open or closed? Maybe there is another way to find that out.